# Passing values to jDialog and run proc on opening

Tags: java, parameters, jdialog

I need to program such behavior:
from main frame with buttonlistener I open "history" window (jDialog? jFrame?).
This "history" window should execute query against database with parameter (Param)
passed from main window and bring results on opening.

So I created DlgHistory with private iParam and method to set it.
But where should I put my proc getHistory to be run?
If I set it at the end of "public DlgHistory()" - it runs before setParam, so iParam is empty 
(although is set properly later)

calling window:

```
JButton btnHistory = new JButton("History");
btnHistory.setBounds(176, 413, 113, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnHistory);
btnHistory.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Running history");
    DlgHistory Hist= new DlgHistory();
    Hist.setParam(iParam);
    Hist.setVisible(true);  
});
```

History jDialog:

```
public class DlgHistory extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private int iParam;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DlgHistory dialog = new DlgHistory();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public DlgHistory() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        {
            // buttons definitions
        }
        // This proc should run after setParam
        getHistory(iParam);
    }
    public void setParam(int Param){
        System.out.println("Setting param" + Param);
        this.iParam = Param;
    }

    private void getHistory(int iParam) {
        System.out.println(" run query with param:  "  " + iParam);
        // run query
    }

}
```

Comment: have for an instance Broker class with a method that will to your query and result set operations...and then call the dialog with a parameter set to be the result of the previous function.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton btnHistory = new JButton("History");
btnHistory.setBounds(176, 413, 113, 23);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnHistory);
btnHistory.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Running history");
   //Some function that will do your query
    iParam=somefunction();
    DlgHistory Hist= new DlgHistory(iParam);
    Hist.setVisible(true);  
});
```

and make changes to DlgHistory constructor and do with it what you initially did

Comment: thanx! 
And from side of dlgHistory? How it will know it has a parameter?
May I concentrate all logic inside dlgHist, because I will need fill jTable from results of query and may be rerun query from inside?